# Apply transformation on an image on C# for a Windows Phone application

Tags: c#, windows-phone, transform, translation

I'm working on a mini-game where I need to make images go from their initial position to another using a translation transformation.

The problem is: I don't know how to proceed to apply the translation.

So here's the code used to generate my images.

```
Image myImage1 = new Image();
myImage1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/image1.png", UriKind.Relative));
myImage1.Name = "image" + index++.ToString();
myImage1.Tap += myImage_Tap;

Canvas.SetLeft(image, 200);
Canvas.SetTop(image, 600);

gameArea.Children.Add(image);
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two choices to move your image around. The first is using a Canvas like your code shows, but you have to make sure your element is actually within a Canvas. Is your "gameArea" a Canvas? If it's not, your code won't work.  The other option is to use Transforms.

```
var myImage1 = new Image
{
    Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Images/image1.png", UriKind.Relative)),
    Name = "image" + index++.ToString(),
    Tap += myImage_Tap,
    RenderTransform = new TranslateTransform
    {
        X = 200,
        Y = 600
    }
};

gameArea.Children.Add(image);
```

Now gameArea can be any type of Panel and it will work.

Note that when using a Canvas, your Top and Left will be from the upper left corner of the Canvas. When using a Transform, your X and Y will be relative to where the element would have originally be drawn.

UPDATE -- Helper class to do simple animations using a Canvas

```
public sealed class ElementAnimator
{
    private readonly UIElement _element;

    public ElementAnimator(UIElement element)
    {
        if (null == element)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("element", "Element can't be null.");
        }

        _element = element;
    }

    public void AnimateToPoint(Point point, int durationInMilliseconds = 300)
    {
        var duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(durationInMilliseconds));

        var easing = new BackEase
        {
            Amplitude = .3
        };

        var sb = new Storyboard
        {
            Duration = duration
        };

        var animateLeft = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            From = Canvas.GetLeft(_element),
            To = point.X,
            Duration = duration,
            EasingFunction = easing,
        };

        var animateTop = new DoubleAnimation
        {
            From = Canvas.GetTop(_element),
            To = point.Y,
            Duration = duration,
            EasingFunction = easing,
        };

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animateLeft, "(Canvas.Left)");
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animateLeft, _element);

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animateTop, "(Canvas.Top)");
        Storyboard.SetTarget(animateTop, _element);

        sb.Children.Add(animateLeft);
        sb.Children.Add(animateTop);

        sb.Begin();
    }
}
```

Comment: What you did there generates an image in a different point than the point I want. 
What I desire is to generate my image on the point {X=200, Y=600} and make it move to the top so the Y comes from 600 to 0. And I want the animation to be visible, not just generate the image in an other point.

Comment: Is there a way to make it as an animation an add a duration to it ?

Comment: @TahaBenabdallah See my updated answer. I've included a class I made a while ago to help with canvas animations. You need to use storyboards. Storyboards could also animate your Transform values if you don't use a Canvas.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what I did with your code, I took just this part and made it a function:

```
public void AnimateToPoint(UIElement image, Point point, int durationInMilliseconds = 300)
{
    var duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(durationInMilliseconds));

    var sb = new Storyboard
    {
        Duration = duration
    };

    var animateTop = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        From = Canvas.GetTop(image),
        To = point.Y,
        Duration = duration
    };

    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animateTop, new PropertyPath("Canvas.Top")); // You can see that I made some change here because I had an error with what you gave me
    Storyboard.SetTarget(animateTop, image);

    sb.Children.Add(animateTop);

    sb.Begin();
}
```

And then I made the call with:

```
Point myPoint = new Point(leftpos, 300); // leftpos is a variable generated randomly
AnimateToPoint(myImage, myPoint);
```

So now there is still a single error, and it's in the instruction "sb.Begin;".
And it says: Cannot resolve TargetProperty Canvas.Top on specified object.
I reaylly don't know how to proceed.
Thanks for your previous answer!

Comment: @ManOVision Can you have a look at this please?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I never got a notification. The problem is the PropertyPath syntax. Note the extra parentheses in my sample. The syntax is weird and it always takes me a few tries to get it right. If you can declare the storyboard in xaml, it is much easier, but since you are making a game, the elements are probably dynamic so you'll need the proper string syntax in the PropertyPath.

Comment: I'll test out your code tomorrow when I have my PC.